# Monkey patching - changes are not reflected in other modules

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I'd like to edit a method from a Python class without changing source code (package lightgbm). This class is called by other modules, but my changes are not reflected in those.

Here is my code (I'm editing below self.__higher_better_inner_eval):

```
class Booster_fix(lightgbm.basic.Booster):

    def __get_eval_info(self):
        """Get inner evaluation count and names."""
        if self.__need_reload_eval_info:
            self.__need_reload_eval_info = False
            out_num_eval = ctypes.c_int(0)
            # Get num of inner evals
            _safe_call(_LIB.LGBM_BoosterGetEvalCounts(
                self.handle,
                ctypes.byref(out_num_eval)))
            self.__num_inner_eval = out_num_eval.value
            if self.__num_inner_eval > 0:
                # Get name of evals
                tmp_out_len = ctypes.c_int(0)
                reserved_string_buffer_size = 255
                required_string_buffer_size = ctypes.c_size_t(0)
                string_buffers = [
                    ctypes.create_string_buffer(reserved_string_buffer_size) for i in range_(self.__num_inner_eval)
                ]
                ptr_string_buffers = (ctypes.c_char_p * self.__num_inner_eval)(*map(ctypes.addressof, string_buffers))
                _safe_call(_LIB.LGBM_BoosterGetEvalNames(
                    self.handle,
                    ctypes.c_int(self.__num_inner_eval),
                    ctypes.byref(tmp_out_len),
                    ctypes.c_size_t(reserved_string_buffer_size),
                    ctypes.byref(required_string_buffer_size),
                    ptr_string_buffers))
                if self.__num_inner_eval != tmp_out_len.value:
                    raise ValueError("Length of eval names doesn't equal with num_evals")
                if reserved_string_buffer_size < required_string_buffer_size.value:
                    raise BufferError(
                        "Allocated eval name buffer size ({}) was inferior to the needed size ({})."
                        .format(reserved_string_buffer_size, required_string_buffer_size.value)
                    )
                self.__name_inner_eval = \
                    [string_buffers[i].value.decode('utf-8') for i in range_(self.__num_inner_eval)]
                self.__higher_better_inner_eval = \
                    [name.startswith(('auc', 'ndcg@', 'map@', 'average_precision')) for name in self.__name_inner_eval] # replacement row
                    # [name.startswith(('auc', 'ndcg@', 'map@')) for name in self.__name_inner_eval] # original row

lightgbm.basic.Booster = Booster_fix
```

In some other modules, there are call such as:

```
from .basic import Booster
```

And I guess my monkey patching is not working there.

Basically I want to implement this fix: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/pull/3649/commits/f73407f05e389a74e6f44a2cb9c637df6afdb33b without waiting for the released update, and without editing source code.

Could you help me with that please?

edit: @Maurice, to test the code, you can run:

```
import pandas as pd
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier # lgbm version 3.1.1
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv("https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv")
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype('category')
X, y = df.drop(columns=['Name', 'Survived']), df['Survived']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
model = LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=10, eval_metric='average_precision', eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: You need to monkey patch before `from .basic import Booster` is executed. Python caches the imports, so all upcoming imports are going to use the monkey patched version.

Comment: How to do it without editing source code? Source code is using `from .basic import Booster`

Answer (score 1):

You could just patch `__get_eval_info` of `lightgbm.basic.Booster`:

```
from lightgbm.basic import Booster


def patched__get_eval_info(self):
    print("patched ...")
    # your code here


Booster.__get_eval_info = patched__get_eval_info
b = Booster(model_file='model.txt')
b.__get_eval_info()

# ... other imports that use lightgbm follow here
```

Out:

```
patched ...
```

Comment: I tried it, but without success. Your code is cleaner than mine,thanks for pointing it, but problem is still the same, method is not called.

Comment: @mbh86: Can you be more specific (edit your question), what is not working?

Comment: thanks for helping. I edited my question with code to run for the test. I'm not calling Booster object itself, I'm calling LGBMClassifier (which contains a property Booster) and fit method use get_eval_info. `patched ...` doesn't display